# Using __repr__ Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to be able to run this function without needing to add `.elements` to the end. For instance, if `seta=MySet([1,2,3])` and `setb=MySet([1,10,11])`, I can run `setc=seta.intersection(setb.elements)`, but not without the `.elements`. How can I run it without needing to type `.elements`?

```
class MySet:
    def __init__(self, elements):
        self.elements=elements
    def intersection(self, other_set):
        self.other_set=other_set
        new_set = []
        for j in other_set:
            if j in self.elements:
                new_set.append(j)
        new_set.sort()
        return new_set
```

Answer (score 1):

Easily, all you have to do is access the `.elements` in the function. No `__repr__` required.

```
class MySet:
    def __init__(self, elements):
        self.elements=elements
    def intersection(self, setb):
        other_set = setb.elements
        new_set = []
        for j in other_set:
            if j in self.elements:
                new_set.append(j)
        new_set.sort()
        return new_set
```

Answer (score 1):

[Make your set an iterable by defining `__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__):

```
class MySet:
    def __init__(self, elements):
        self.elements=elements
    def intersection(self, other_set):
        ...
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.elements)
        # Or for implementation hiding, so the iterator type of elements
        # isn't exposed:
        # yield from self.elements
```

Now iteration over an instance of `MySet` seamlessly iterates the elements it contains.

I'd strongly suggest looking at [the `collections.abc` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html); you're clearly trying to build a `set`-like object, and getting the basic behaviors in place is easiest by using `collections.abc.Set` (or `collections.abc.MutableSet`) as your base class.